# Calculate reliability in factor analysis

Tags: r

The summary of my question: 
  I am currently doing a factor analysis with 23 items. The procedure is suggested by Andy Field in *Discovering statistics using R.* However, I have a problem calculating the reliability in factor analysis.

More detailed:

```
performance_problem <- .dataset2[, c(17,7,2,11,21)]
A <- dataset2 [, c(8,15,13,21)]
B <- dataset2 [, c(12,6,9,1)]
C <- dataset2[,c(20,14,4)]
D <- dataset2[,c(10,16,3)]
E <- dataset2 [,c(23,19,5)]
```

I defined different items under different factors. For instance, the first factor called performance problems, including the 17th, 7th, 2nd, 11th, 21st item in dataset2. And I received no error running the R code.

There is no negative factor loadings in my factor analysis. So I directly calculated my reliability with this R code:

```
alpha(performance_problem)
```

And I also tried this one:

```
psych:alpha(performance_problem)
```

But none of them works. And the error message I received from R was:

```
Error in grDevices::col2rgb(colour, TRUE) : 
  invalid color name 'c(2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 4, 4, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 6, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 4, 2, 4, 1, 5, 4, 1, 6, 3, 6, 5, 1, 2, 1, 1, 5, 6, 2, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4, 5, 4, 6, 1, 6, 1, 5, 6, 6, 1, 4, 1, 6, 1, 5, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 5, 4, 1, 1, 5, 5, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 5, 6, 6, 3, 1, 6, 1, 3, 1, 6, 4, 3, 3, 1, 1, 5, 3, 5, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 5, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 6, 2, 6, 1, 6, 2, 2, 6, 1, 3, 6, 5, 1, 1, 6, 6, 3, 5, 4, 1, 4, 5, 4, 5, 1, 5, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 1, 5, 6, 1, 6, 2, 5, 2, 1, 1, 3, 6, 1, 4, 4, 1, 2, 4, 6, 1, 1, 1, 
6, 1, 5, 6, 1, 5, 3, 1, 3, 1, 4, 3, 5, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 5, 5, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 6, 1, 1, 1, 5, 4, 2, 5, 6, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 1, 5, 4, 4, 1, 3, 2, 2, 6, 1, 6, 1, 4, 5, 5, 1, 1, 5, 4, 1, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 2, 5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 6, 2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 1, 1, 4, 4, 5, 6, 1, 4, 6, 3, 6, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 6, 1, 4, 6, 5, 1, 2, 6, 2, 5, 1, 5, 4, 5, 1, 3, 1, 4, 3, 3, 1, 5, 2, 4, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 5, 6, 6, 6, 5, 1, 2, 4, 1, 5, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 6, 4, 4, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 5, 1, 5, 1, 1
```

But I do not really understand why I have this problem in R? 
Any help will be really grateful!

Comment: Do you have a sample of the dataset you are referencinng, or perhaps toy data in the same format that you could add to your question? That may be helpful in getting an answer for you.

Comment: `psych:alpha` is incorrect syntax; it should be `::`

Answer (score 0):

Try another method:

```
library(dplyr)
library(psych)
```

Create df only with variables you need for reliability analysis (called df1); 
df2 is your df with all of the initial variables; and variables you want to choose are for example V1:V10

```
df1 <- dplyr::select(df2, V1:V10) 

psych::omega(df1, nfactors = 1) # you get both alpha and omega
```